# ConstraintSet get existing connection

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

How do get the currently connected view for a given direction from a constraint set?

I'm trying to insert an View before another one

```
private void insertBefore(int toInsert,int insertBefore)
{
            ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();

            ConstraintLayout root = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.constraintRoot);
            cs.clone(root);

            int currentAbove = cs.getConnectedView(ConstraintSet.TOP);//this is the part I can figure out

            cs.connect(insertBefore,ConstraintSet.TOP,toInsert,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
            cs.connect(toInsert,ConstraintSet.TOP,currentAbove,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

            root.setConstraintSet(cs);
}
```

The above is more or less what I am trying to do. I can't find anything in the ConstraintSet [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet) mentioning a function similar to the above function `getConnectedView()`

I could add an `insertAfter` parameter to the function but I would rather avoid that.

Here is a diagram of what I want to accomplish
[image]

Comment: Questions: Do you get two `view` id's that already exist in Layout or haven't been added yet? What exactly do you want to do with this method?

Comment: Both of the views already exist in the layout. I am moving a view that is off to the side to inline with the center views

Comment: So, does the "insertBefore" `view` already have the correct constraint and does the "toInsert" `view` need to have its constraint changed?

Comment: @MoisésCunha I've added a diagram, `insertBefore` needs to have it's top constraint changed to point at `toInsert`. and `toInsert` needs to have it's top changed to point at `insertAfter`. I'm also changing the side connections for `toInsert` but I didn't include them in the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See if this works for you**

```
private void insertBefore(@IdRes int toInsert, @IdRes int insertBefore) {
    ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout root = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintRoot);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(insertBefore).getLayoutParams();

    cs.clone(root);

    cs.clear(toInsert, ConstraintSet.END);
    cs.clear(toInsert, ConstraintSet.START);

    cs.connect(toInsert, ConstraintSet.TOP, params.topToBottom != -1 ? params.topToBottom : params.topToTop, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    cs.connect(toInsert, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    cs.connect(toInsert, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);

    cs.connect(insertBefore, ConstraintSet.TOP, toInsert, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    cs.connect(insertBefore, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    cs.connect(insertBefore, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);

    cs.applyTo(root);
}
```